# Why does a nested margin affect the body tag?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to layout a somewhat simple page with a navigation drawer and an app bar.  The nav drawer should be the full height of the page, the app bar should be at the top of the page and the full width of the area that is not covered by the nav drawer.  The page content should then be to the right of the nav drawer and beneath the app bar.

```
<div class="nav-drawer"></div>
<div class="nav-drawer-adjust">
  <div class="app-bar"></div>
  <div class="app-bar-adjust">Page content here</div>
</div>
```

The `.nav-drawer-adjust` has a left margin to push the rest of the page to the right of the nav drawer.  The `.app-bar-adjust` has a top margin to push the page content beneath the app bar.

```
.nav-drawer {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 256px;
}

.nav-drawer-adjust {
  width: calc(100% - 256px);
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 256px;
}

.app-bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
}

.app-bar-adjust {
  margin-top: 64px;
  height: calc(100% - 64px);
}
```

However, with that HTML and that CSS, I get this result:

[image: body is not at the top of the page]

The `margin-top` on the `.app-bar-adjust` seems to "set" where the top of the `body` element is. And because the `body` is no longer at the top of the page, the `.app-bar` isn't either.  But why??  Can someone please explain what is happening?

[Here is a Code Pen](https://codepen.io/zposten/pen/NWPwMBe?editors=1100) of the situation.

---

I can "fix" this problem in one of two ways:

1. By adding a wrapper element with `display: flex`.  That makes sense, but I don't understand why it is necessary
2. By changing the `margin-top` on `.app-bar-adjust` to be a `padding-top` instead.  But this is undesirable for other layout reasons.

But these two solutions are both workarounds and I don't think address the actual problem here.

Comment: Would changing the positioning of the `app-bar` div to `fixed` be the solution to your problem? See Codepen example: https://codepen.io/mikehermary/pen/qBEVKXx?editors=1100

Comment: (1) flex can fix this because there is no margin-collapsing in flexbox context (2) padding doesn't collapse with margin